# Annoying bug in the rendering

Tags: rendering, opengl-3, texture2d, light, oculus

I am trying to port the roomTiny example from the Oculus SDK to Jogl

I already ported most of the program, but I am stuck on an annoying bug since a couple of days and I am going crazy

After a couple of days, I tried to make a new simplified copy in order to find the bug, but I experience exactly the same..

I ask if someone out there would like to help me

I can render properly only the floor or the ceiling, not both

https://github.com/elect86/JavaOculusRoomTiny/tree/master/src/roomTinySimplified

Only floor

[image]

Only ceiling

[image]

both

[image]

The program is pretty simple, there is (at the moment) only one glsl program for litTextures

You add Model and in the rendering loop you update lights (in an ubo) and loop the models themselves rendering them

In the same model rendering, I initialize everything about, vbo, ibo and texture

The vbo data are 100% exact, I scanned each vertex attribute one by one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gl3.glDrawElements(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL3.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ibo[0]);

instead

gl3.glDrawElements(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL3.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);